# Join two tables based on the partial matched column

Tags: hive, hql

i want to join two tables in hive based on the partial match. So far, i tried with the below SQL query:

```
select * from tableA a join tableB b on a.id like '%'+b.id+'%';
   and instr but nothing working, is there a way?
```

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` in Hive only support equation conditions. Plus, you should use `CONCAT` for your string concatenation.

This is one solution instead.

```
select *
from tableA a, tableB b
where a.id like concat('%',b.id,'%')
```